# AttributeError: 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'excute'

Tags: python, forms, flask, syntax-error, mysql-connector

I create register system that can check what user or email that already used and i have got error AttributeError: 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'excute' [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX7tz.png)
that i use flask framework and python and please describe DictCursor attribute or some solution for me

```
###############insert value(register)##########

@app.route('/new',methods=['GET','POST'])
def user_value():
if request.method=='POST':
    if "one" in request.form and "two" in request.form and "three" in request.form:
        username = request.form['one']
        email = request.form['two']
        password = request.form['three']
        cur = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        ###check DATA###
        curs=cur.excute("SELECT * FROM my_db.user_accout WHERE username =%s AND email =%s",thwart(username, email))
        if int(curs)>0:
            flash("User and email already used")
            return render_template("register.html")
        else:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_db.user_accout(username,email,password) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",(username,email,password))
            db.connection.commit()
            return redirect(url_for("index"))
                
        
        
        
return render_template("register.html")



######show IP in terminal(debugger)#####

if __name__ =='__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback, as _text_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are confusing two different libraries.
`import MySQLdb` and `from flask_mysqldb import MySQL` are two different libraries.

Since you are using `flask` adding this line `app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'` and then calling the cursor `cursor=db.connection.cursor()` should solve your problem.

Taken from the [official git page](https://github.com/alexferl/flask-mysqldb)